# Where the process of the service?

Tags: pid

At UBUNTU, `service postgresql status` lists

```
  Process: 18534 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 18534 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

but when I test `sudo ps -ax | grep 18534` nothing is listed.

---

### NOTES

EDIT1 for @DanielB request, but I need a simple command that shows **any** *service* PID.

Here a dump `more /lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service`,

```
# systemd service for managing all PostgreSQL clusters on the system. This
# service is actually a systemd target, but we are using a service since
# targets cannot be reloaded.

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL RDBMS

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=on

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

EDIT2

The PostgreSQL above was my localhost server... Now I am testing in a "new, clean and shine" DigitalOcean Droplet with UBUNTU 16 LTS and Postgresql 9.X...

```
root@myServer:~# service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Dom 2016-12-18 17:47:09 UTC; 2 weeks 4 days ago
 Main PID: 8703 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service

Dez 18 17:47:09 myServer systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Dez 18 17:47:09 myServer systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
Dez 18 17:47:14 myServer systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.


root@myServer:~# sudo ps -ax | grep  8703
 3702 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto 8703

root@myServer:~# sudo service postgresql restart

root@myServer:~# sudo ps -ax | grep  8703
 3760 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto 8703


root@myServer:~# service postgresql status
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sex 2017-01-06 16:06:07 UTC; 8s ago
  Process: 3755 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 3755 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 06 16:06:07 myServer systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Jan 06 16:06:07 myServer systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.


sudo ps -ax | grep  3755
 3780 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto 3755
```

Comment: Well, `/bin/true` is obviously not the service. It’s also marked as exited. Please provide the contents of `/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service`.

Comment: Hi @DanielB, I Edited with the dump.

Comment: For other service, as `service postfix status` it is ok (!). The problem with PostgreSQL is perhaps a kind of "thread activation"... Perhaps I need the service in use at `top`, is it?

Comment: “I need a simple command that shows any service PID.” – That’s probably not going to happen. That being said, what the f is this. 

Comment: It seems to me that `postgresql` is not running. Processes have exit code after they exited, it makes no sense to mention exit code of a currently running process.

Comment: @janos This service does obviously not start PostgreSQL. It is part of some sort of bad hack.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/818838/postgresql-exits-after-being-started This explains what’s going on. I still think it’s bs.

Comment: @janos the service is alive, as I showed (and now confirm). ... I not know the behaviour of  *daemon* (and its PIDs), perhaps we need better knowledge about it... As link above of Daniel.

Comment: @PeterKrauss you didn't show it is alive. You could try something though. What port is the service listening on? If you are on Linux (please confirm), then you can verify the port is up by running `sudo netstat -ntlp | grep :the-port-number`. This command will also show the process id. Include this info in your question.

Comment: Thanks @janos, see my EDIT2. About port:  `sudo netstat -ntlp | grep 5432` shows `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3738/postgres` (for both machines).

Comment: @janos yes! you find, "LISTEN 3738/postgres"  is the PID!  ... `sudo ps -ax | grep 3738` now returns 
 `3738 ?        S      0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main -c`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none, because as you can see yourself from the unit's contents, `postgresql.service` does not actually start any daemon. It exists merely as a 'parent' service to group together various instances of `postgresql@.service` (i.e. to reload all of them at once). Instead take a look at:

```
systemctl status postgresql@\*.service
```

Comment: Perfect! Hum... But it is generic?  `systemctl status postfix@\*.service` show nothing, despite the `service postfix status`  show PIDs.

Comment: @PeterKrauss: They are actually two different services. `postgresql@.service` was explicitly named such in order to be multi-instance (see its contents), and later on, a separate `postgresql.service` was added to do the 'reload' trick – perhaps because back then systemctl didn't yet support the wildcards, or maybe someone just felt lazy.

Comment: Hum.. ok (!), the syntax is `systemctl status postfix.service`, it works fine! So it is generic!  "use systemctl instead service" is the best answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The PID of the service doesn't seem to be indicated anywhere in here:

> ```
>   Process: 18534 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>  Main PID: 18534 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
> ```

I say that because this message talks about exit code, which doesn't make sense for a running process. Only terminated processes have exit code.

If the postgres service is running, in a GNU/Linux system you can find its PID in the output of `sudo netstat -ntlp | grep posgres`, for example:

```
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:5432 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 3738/postgres
```

In this kind of output, 3738 is the PID.

As a side note, to verify a process by PID, instead of running `ps -ax | grep the-pid`, it's better to do `ps -p the-pid`.